# Finding the children clicked nodeName within the parent element

Tags: jquery, html

Consider this simple **html** list :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Test2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://google.com">Test2 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Test2 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now this 3 **jQuery** lines which makes it collapsible :

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(); 
});
```

The matter here is that if a link has been clicked in the deeper `ul` I wanted it to follow the link, which in jQuery will be :

```
if(this.nodeName != 'A') {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

At the moment the `nodeName` is `LI` and isn't the last clicked child element.

**Question** : Is it possible to do this *without having a second event handler for deeper elements* ? (i.e : `$('ul > li ul li a').click()`)

I tried `e.stopPropagation` and a lots of other `css selectors` (`ul > *`, `ul li` etc.) without success.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do.

What's the expected behaviour in this line:
`<li><a href="http://google.com/">Test2</a> <ul> ...`

Open google or toggle the underlying list?

Comment: @FriederikeS It's because it's a responsive menu which (on desktops) will follow that first link on click. But it's not the point here and it was just because I got a link here in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I came to this answer :

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();

    if(!$(this).find('ul').length == 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();     
    } 
});
```

So it'll follow links if no `ul` element is founded in the clicked element. If you've got a better solution please share :).

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajGAW/).

This solution won't work with a specified `ul` by `ID` :

```
$('ul#test > li').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();

    if(!$(this).find('ul').length == 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();     
    } 
});
```

See [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajGAW/1/), can somebody explain why ?

Ok thanks to `Simon` I've corrected with my listener on the `li` from the `ul#test` :

```
$('ul#test').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();

    if(!$(this).find('ul').length == 0) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();     
    } 
});
```

Wonderful !

Comment: Because when using the ID of the main UL you restrict all events to this one element. With UL > LI it applies to the descendent lists too. Try using the event delegation of .on(): `$('#test').on('click', 'li', function() {});`, like this you bind the event listener only on one parent and it gets the clicked element through `event.target`.

Comment: Like Simon said. In your example, this one works: $('ul#test li').on('click', function(e) {...}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('li > ul').prev().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F26PH/) the link to the jsfiddle.Here the `li > ul` selector find each `ul` child of `li` then `.prev()` selects the previosu sibling (i.e. the `a` tag). This way we can prevent the default behaviour of `a` tag (i.e. following the link) and slideToggle the next (i.e. the `ul`)

Answer (score 0):

Since your root selector is `'ul > li'` it will match nothing but LIs. i.e. There is no way you'll be matching clicks to other elements inside a handler bound using that selector.

What you can do instead is a more generic selector and filter inside the handler:

For example:

```
$('ul *').on('click', function(e) {

    // leaf LIs only
    if($(this).is('li') && $(this).children().length == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();  
    }

});
```

---

OR, You can combine the selectors and handle it using *one* handler like:

```
$('ul > li, ul > li ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).is('a')) return true; // follow links
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(); 
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying not to do.

Comment: `$(this).children().length == 0` won't work if `<li>` contains `<ul>` am I right ?